# How to calculate number of all atoms in rings in a molecule?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Is there a way or a formula to find number of all atoms in all rings?
EDIT : I wanna explain it with pictures : [image: Anthracene with hydrogens]

this is an anthracene which have 14 atoms in ring.
what thing it has that is 14?
2nd EDIT:
i have number of atoms bonds rings carbon atoms oxygen atoms and ... the connections.I want a formula with these things also i want it to work for no ring molecules like C2H4.

Comment: for example: anthracene have 14 members

Comment: Count them all one by one, that's the way. As for the formula, what good it would do if I say that it is "4n+2"?

Comment: im using it for programming project

Comment: Let's put it another way. By doing a programming project, you probably have some information about some molecule(s) encoded in your computer, in bits and bytes. ***What is that information?*** What is it that you know about your molecule(s)? Obviously not the number of carbons. Then what?

Comment: Try to be nice, folks. This person is a new member and is only looking for guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That 'thing that has 14' is the *Smallest Set of Smallest Rings*, or SSSR. Calculating the SSSR is a perennial problem in cheminformatics. Treatises have been written about this subject.

Many ring perception algorithms have been devised, and they are too numerous to list here.

I would start with this paper:

Downs, G. M., Gillet, V. J., Holliday, J. D., & Lynch, M. F. (1989). *Review of ring perception algorithms for chemical graphs*. *AUGUST*. https://doi.org/10.1021/ci00063a007

which gives an introduction to the subject. As it's an old paper, you could then move onto:

May, J. W., & Steinbeck, C. (2014). Efficient ring perception for the Chemistry Development Kit. *Journal of Cheminformatics*, *6*(1), 1–12. https://doi.org/10.1186/1758-2946-6-3
which then describes some more modern approaches to the problem.

**EDIT**

'i have number of atoms bonds rings carbon atoms oxygen atoms and ... the connections.I want a formula with these things also i want it to work for no ring molecules like C2H4.'

You're not asking much, are you?!
What you are talking about, in essence, is *cheminformatics*. Representing chemical structures using computers.

It's a well established and very significant discipline.
I'd start with this book:
[https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Chemoinformatics-Andrew-R-Leach/dp/1402013477](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1402013477)

It's a really good introduction to the discipline.

Comment: so its a hard problem right?

Comment: No, not especially. It can be computationally expensive, but eh algorithms themselves aren't that difficult once you understand how to use them.
Our very own software, https://www.chem4word.co.uk/, uses the Figueras algorithm to calculate the SSSR. We use that because it's quick. But there are so many other algorithms you can just take your pick.
One of the originals  is detailed in
Use of Ring Assemblies in Ring Perception Algorithm
Journal of Chemical Information and Computer Sciences, (1975), 140-147, 15(3)
You got to do some library legwork. There is no way around that.

Comment: The easiest way to find the *number* of rings in a structure is to use Eulers formula: rings = bonds - atoms +1 . (Counting multiple bonds as single bonds). That will tell you how many rings you've got, but not what their members are.
For instance, for benzene, rings = 12-12+1 = 1. Napthalene = 19 - 18 +1 = 2. Etc